# Flutter: How to wait for android platform channel function to complete and return the result

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

Creating a platform channel on Android for File upload using AWS SDK.
Now I want to wait for the upload to complete in the background and return the status of the result.

```
MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "uploadToAWS") {
                new DoUpload().execute();

                // how to await here ?
                result.success(true);
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
```

Comment: simply call `result.success(true);` when you are done with uploading

Comment: can I call the result.success(true) from inside a delegate function?

Comment: you can call it from everywhere, the only restriction is described [here](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.Result.html) - read the second paragraph

Comment: the easiest way is something like this: `new DoUpload(result).execute();` - so you can access `result` inside your `DoUpload` class

Comment: @pskink That's not a good idea -- `onMethodCall` runs on the UI thread, so if you are waiting for the upload to complete before returning from the method call, you are blocking the Android UI thread.

Comment: @LukeHutchison 4 years later..., hmmm but `onMethodCall` is ending without blocking, or I missed something? what I meant was to pass `result` to background task in order to call `success` on it

Comment: @pksink if `DoUpload().execute()` is a blocking method, then you need to launch that on another thread (not the UI thread), and pass in the result object. Then when that other thread's blocking method has completed, you call `result.success(true)`.

Comment: @LukeHutchison OP said: "Now I want to wait for the upload to complete in the *background*" so I assume he has some not blocking thread

Answer (score 6):

1. Instead of waiting there, remove "result.success(true);" statement from there and simply assign "result" object to your own object of type "MethodChannel.Result".
2. Then use it to execute its "success", "error" or "notImplemented" method from anywhere as shown in below example.

   ```
   public class Activity extends FlutterActivity {

     private MethodChannel.Result myResult;

     new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
           .setMethodCallHandler(
                   (call, result) -> {
                       myResult = result;
                   }
           );

     private void myCustomMethod {

       myResult.success(yourData);

     }

   }
   ```

Now you can use these myResult.success(), myResult.error() methods from anywhere within class.

Comment: This is not working for me. myResult is always null. I am using kotlin.