# Flutter Android intent ActivityResult

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have to solve following problem:
Calling an Intent from Flutter, waiting for finish the process of the Intent, and return the result to Flutter (call a card reader app trough intent, read the card, and return if the reading process is success or not).
The code in my Flutter app is:

```
  Future<List<String>?> startActivityForResult(double amount, String operation)async {
    const platform = const MethodChannel('reader');
    try {
      final String? result = await platform.invokeMethod('StartReading',<String, dynamic>{
        "Amount" : amount,
        "Operation" : operation,
        "TransactionID" : Uuid().v1()
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Error: ${e.message}');
    }
  }
```

code in MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "reader"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.

            call, result ->
            var REQ_CODE: Int = 1;
            var RES_CODE: Int = -1;

            if (call.method == "StartReading") {
                var JSON: JSONObject = JSONObject();
                JSON.put("Amount", call.argument("Amount"));
                JSON.put("Operation", call.argument("Operation"));
                JSON.put("TransactionID",call.argument("TransactionID"));
                var intent: Intent = Intent();
                intent.component = ComponentName("co.reader.posterminal", "co.reader.posterminal.MainActivity");
                intent.putExtra("POS_EMULATOR_EXTRA",JSON.toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
                onActivityResult(REQ_CODE,RES_CODE, intent);
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }

            @Override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
                    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
                        try {
                            var Result: String? = data?.getStringExtra("POS_EMULATOR_RESULT");
                            var JSONResult: JSONObject = JSONObject(Result);
                            result.success(Result);
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.println(Log.ERROR,"Error: ",e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The reading process start well (startActivityForResult), reading process is also ok, but i don't get any result.
Can anybody solve, why?

Comment: Try this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64135497/9231721 worked for me. I'm also using it for pos.